# Cannot implicitly convert type 'MongoDB.Driver.DeleteResult' to 'T'

Tags: c#, mongodb, generics

I'm using MongoDB in my MVC project and am creating a utility function that I could use to delete records in database.

I am using :

- mongo db extension for C#
- C#(.net 4.6.1)

To method is passed record what I want to delete.
I filter all recordings in DB by id of passed recording what I want to delete.
Finding it I want to delete it.
my method

```
public virtual async Task<T> Delete(EmailBlastDocument input)
        {
            var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Id, input.Id);
            
            var collection = DocumentContext.DocumentClient.GetDatabase(DatabaseName).GetCollection<T>(CollectionName);

            return await collection.DeleteOneAsync(filter);

        }
```

But it highlights error on compile time

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'MongoDB.Driver.DeleteResult' to 'T'
```

How do I fix this function to properly return the result of delete record to the caller? And how to properly delete record in mongoDB

I have create Update method what was took as example

```
public virtual async Task<T> Update(T input)
        {
            var collection = DocumentContext.DocumentClient.GetDatabase(DatabaseName).GetCollection<T>(CollectionName);
            try
            {
                await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(a => a.Id == input.Id, input);
            }
            catch (MongoWriteException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.WriteError.Category)
                {
                    case ServerErrorCategory.ExecutionTimeout:
                        throw new TimeoutException();
                    default:
                        throw new CirrusDocumentGeneralException();
                }
            }
            return input;
        }
```

Comment: What is the basis for your expectation that you can cast `DeleteResult` to your document type (`T`)? What do you want to return?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Well at first delete recording in db at second the 'The result of the delete operation.'

Comment: I don't understand your reply. Please can you try phrasing it differently?

Comment: Why do you want to return T?

Comment: @Tinneveld.N  @DiplomacyNotWar I took as example already made Update method(posted in question). I am newbie in MongoDB and int MongoDB driver in C# I do not know how method should properly looks like. As I mention I took as example already existing methods what returns `The result of the operation`.

Comment: In your update method, you are returning `input`, not the `ReplaceOneResult` result returned by `ReplaceOneAsync`. In your Delete method, you are trying to return the `DeleteResult` returned by `DeleteOneAsync`. Clearly the existing method isn't the basis for the new method.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Well all methods before I created my are in return type `public virtual async Task<T>` so I assumed what delete method also must by Task<T>. Maybe I am wrong but I want same return type for delete method.

Comment: OK, so are you saying you don't want to return `input` in your delete method? Or what?

Comment: He wants to keep Task<T> instead of changing it to the return type of the method he wants to return.

Comment: @Tinneveld.N In that case, why does OP's method accept `EmailBlastDocument`rather than `T`?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Not sure but if wants to follow the example of the Update method he should indeed change it to T and return that value.

Comment: a generic parameter generally means: this method is intended to be used for all types that match the generic constraint. As you don't have any constraint, this is implictely `object` (or "all" types). So your method can handle every type that exists, not just a few mongo-types. You should either add a constraint like `where T: MyType` or replace `T` by `MyType`, depending on if or if not thie method should be generic.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain It seems likely the generic constraint is applied at the class level, as the `Update` method is (apparently) working despite the code using `input.Id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not 100% clear what you're trying to do here. I'm also not sure why the method accepts a `EmailBlastDocument` and not a `T`. I'm assuming it should be `T`.

If you want to change it to work similarly to `Update` you could change it to be like this:

```cs
public virtual async Task<T> Delete(T input)
{
    var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Id, input.Id);
    
    var collection = DocumentContext.DocumentClient.GetDatabase(DatabaseName).GetCollection<T>(CollectionName);

    await collection.DeleteOneAsync(filter); // do the delete
    return input; // return the input
}
```

This will return the input document as a result of the delete. Note that the `input` document could be different to the last value in the database.

If you want to return the absolute latest version of the document, you can use `FindOneAndDeleteAsync`:

```cs
public virtual async Task<T> Delete(T input)
{
    var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Id, input.Id);

    var collection = DocumentContext.DocumentClient.GetDatabase(DatabaseName).GetCollection<T>(CollectionName);

    return await collection.FindOneAndDeleteAsync(filter);
}
```

This will return the document as it was inn the database just before it got deleted.